# Printing an arrow head using stars

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out an arrow head using *s.
So far my code looks like this.

```
def head(n):
    while n > 0:
        print n * "*"
        n = n - 1

print head(input())
```

and it works but if for example I enter 11, it prints this:

```
***********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

But I want it to print like this:

```
     *    
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Which has less arrows, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Use the center() method of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def printHead(n):
    for l in range(1,n):
        print " "*(n-l)+"*"*(1 if l==1 else 2*l-1)
```

Each row has `level-1` spaces. Then if it's the first level one start, otherwise it has `2*level-1`.

```
>>> printHead(6)
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes the function a little simpler to think in terms of how many lines do you want:

```
def head(lines):
    for n in range(1,lines*2,2):           # count 1,3,5...
        print(('*'*n).center(lines*2-1))
```

Output:

```
>>> head(5)
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

Here's an alternate way to use a variable length format that is a little less obvious:

```
def head(lines):
    for n in range(1,lines*2,2):
        print('{:^{}}'.format('*'*n,lines*2-1))
```

Comment: +1 for the string formatting, beats my concatenation approach!

Answer (score 2):

use string formatting:

```
def head(size):
    n=1
    while n < size+1:
        stars = n * "*"
        print '{:^30}'.format(stars)
        n += 2
```

it will center your asterisks on the field 30 chars wide.

Comment: you should use an odd width

Comment: [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) is a built-in, consider changing the name.

Answer (score 0):

1. The number of stars on a line is equal to 2n - 1 where n is the line number.
2. I wouldn't call the parameter "n" in this function as it is not clear to me whether it refers to lines or stars.
3. You can use the `center` function to surround a string with whitespace, based on a specified width. You want the arrow to be centred around the longest line so you need 2 variables, one to keep track of the current line and another to remember the largest line.
4. You want to iterate in the opposite direction to what you have demonstrated, as you want the arrow to point up, not down.

I think this should work for you:

```
def head(total_lines):
  for current_line in range(1, total_lines + 1):
    print ((2 * current_line - 1) * "*").center(2 * total_lines - 1)
```

Comment: Not valid Python.  Use `for n in range(1,n+1,2)`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks I broke out Python and answered it properly!

Answer (score 0):

```
def head(n):
    total = 2 * n - 1
    s = ''
    for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
        k = 2 * i - 1
        s += ' ' * ((total - k) / 2) + '*' * k + '\n'
    return s
```